# Slitherlink with a message

Tags: cipher, slitherlink

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

After pondering what my next puzzle would be about I decided to change my base towards the realm of slitherlink puzzles.

I found [this](https://krazydad.com/slitherlink/variety.php) krazy site containing a variety of non-standard grid slitherlink puzzles, and took some inspiration from there.

This is my favorite form: it contains squares, pentagons, hexagons, heptagons as well as octagons.

There is a question hidden in this puzzle, if you can answer it you earn the check mark.

[image: slitherlink_puzzle]

Hint:

> There is a hint in the flavourtext

Hint 2:

> The digits in green form one big number

Comment: can we have another hint, please? :)

Comment: @ArturoVialArqueros Sure, here it is!

Comment: I was almost sure that was the way to go, but the confirmation helped me narrow down the possibilities :D Puzzle solved!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved Slitherlink:

> [image: Completed Grid]

Now, getting the question from the solved grid:

> If we note the number of sides used by the highlighted shapes and write them all together, we get the string 10127723165147052514546427056312254361. None of its digits is greater than 7 (because every shape has 8 sides or less), so we can treat it like octal (Flavor text hints to changing bases). If we convert it from octal (base 8) to a handy base 26 using the alphabet...

We get the question, which is:

> 'How do Guam Tree Snakes climb?'

Thematically, the answer is that:

> The 'lasso' themselves around the trunks of the trees, which can be stated as saying that the snakes "slither" and "link" themselves to climb the trees!

Comment: That's two loops, not one.

Comment: @ArturoVialArqueros There is one error in the colored cell numbers you filled in.

Comment: Oh, I see, one loop. Your yellow cells confused me.

Comment: Sarsaparilla, you're correct, I missed a number. I also changed the coloring to make the loop easier to read @aschepler

Comment: The "6" near center left is really "0".

Comment: @ArturoVialArqueros Well done!